# pandas resample apply np.average

Tags: python, pandas, resampling, pandas-apply

I have time series "half hour" data.  I need to resample `demand` to "1 day" using weighted average (using `price`) during the resample.

`dft`

```
                           demand  price
2012-01-01 00:00:00  30940.500000  42.18
2012-01-01 00:30:00  31189.166667  43.48
2012-01-01 01:00:00  30873.166667  42.28
2012-01-01 01:30:00  30110.833333  38.48
2012-01-01 02:00:00  29721.500000  37.28
2012-01-01 02:30:00  28970.000000  36.24
2012-01-01 03:00:00  27955.000000  32.16
                          ...    ...
2014-12-30 20:30:00  41685.500000  40.51
2014-12-30 21:00:00  40177.833333  41.79
2014-12-30 21:30:00  38238.000000  31.50
2014-12-30 22:00:00  36395.333333  37.54
2014-12-30 22:30:00  34543.333333  39.55
2014-12-30 23:00:00  32652.000000  40.88
2014-12-30 23:30:00  30941.333333  38.16
```

I'd like to resample `demand` to `1D` (1 day), using the `price` column as weights, using `np.average()`

I have looked at a few examples, but something is not quite clicking. The closest I have got is:

```
dftwei = dft.price.resample('1D').apply(lambda x: np.average(x, weights=dft.demand, axis=0))
```

But the problem is this gives:

```
ValueError: Length of weights not compatible with specified axis.
```

When `axis=0` is not specified, the error is:

```
TypeError: Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights differ.
```

The problem probably lies in how `weights` is specified. Weights needs to be a length of 48, but I suspect the lambda function is using the full length of `price`.
Thanks!

Comment: df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: sum(x['price']*x['demand'])/sum(x['demand']))

Comment: Thanks, as in @ayhan  below, I think you want to divide by x['price'], not 'demand'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you only had your subsetting off by a smidgen. To average over the day, resample the whole dataframe and then only average over the day:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([('2012-01-01 00:00', 30940.500000, 42.18),
    ('2012-01-01 00:30', 31189.166667, 43.48),
    ('2012-01-01 01:00', 30873.166667, 42.28),
    ('2012-01-01 01:30', 30110.833333, 38.48),
    ('2012-01-01 02:00', 29721.500000, 37.28),
    ('2012-01-01 02:30', 28970.000000, 36.24),
    ('2012-01-01 03:00', 27955.000000, 32.16),
    ('2012-01-02 20:30', 41685.500000, 40.51),
    ('2012-01-02 21:00', 40177.833333, 41.79),
    ('2012-01-02 21:30', 38238.000000, 31.50),
    ('2012-01-02 22:00', 36395.333333, 37.54),
    ('2012-01-02 22:30', 34543.333333, 39.55),
    ('2012-01-02 23:00', 32652.000000, 40.88),
    ('2012-01-02 23:30', 30941.333333, 38.16)])

df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
df.set_axis(['date', 'demand', 'price'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

#
# Above is just setup, here's the rub:
#
df.resample('1D').apply(lambda x: np.average(x.demand, weights=x.price))
```

Comment: Thanks @heath raftery. I am just checking this. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Heath Raftery.   My DataFrame the same way - but because of slightly older pandas 0.20, the syntax for `set_axis` in this example throws an error. So the key is `x.demand` and not just `x` in `np.average`

Comment: @dreab yes, that frustrated me for ages - I ended up upgrading Pandas to latest (0.22.0), but when I was on 0.20 I had to use `set_axis(1, ['date', 'demand', 'price'])` (order of the first two arguments swapped).

Comment: pandas making sneaky changes so it can remain top of the stackoverflow charts :p

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own weighted average:

```
wp = (df['demand'] * df['price']).resample('H').sum()
wp / df.resample('H')['price'].sum()

2012-01-01 00:00:00    31066.720251
2012-01-01 01:00:00    30509.935034
2012-01-01 02:00:00    29351.065288
2012-01-01 03:00:00    27558.233718
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I have checked and this seems to work.  Interested still to see if   someone knows the correct syntax for `.apply(np.average())`

Comment: also (for others to note): whilst the question I asked was about 1D resample, this solution to aggregate 2 half hours into 1 hour was good as made it easy to check manually.

Comment: @dreab Ah yes I actually changed it so I can confirm the results but forgot to change it while pasting here.